# OSGeo4W Install from Local Directory seems to expect Win32 applications

Tags: qgis, installation, osgeo4w, osgeo

I want to install QGIS 3.18 on a PC running Win7-64bits.
I have manually downloaded all required files (listed in https://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/v1/x86_64/setup.ini) from here:   https://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/v1/x86_64/release/

When I launch osgeo4w-setup.exe, I choose **Advanced Install** \ **Install from Local Directory** and everything seems to go smoothly, except for the follwing postinstall script error (I see no usefull information in the `var\log\setup.log.full` to understand what the problem is):

> Package: Unknown package
> qgis-common.bat exit code -1073741515

When I launch the `OSGeo4W Shell` and try to launch QGIS, I get the following error:

[image: qgis-bin.exe error]

When I click OK, I get a second error:

[image: Error loading QGIS]

Now if I place `icuuc56.dll` in the `OSGeo4W64\bin` folder, I get the following error instead:

[image]

So it seems the installation is somehow expecting Win32 applications whereas I have downloaded files from the `x86_64\release` section so I am expecting them to be 64bits versions.

EDIT: my PC is running Win7-64bits:
[image]

EDIT2: here is the full list of files:

```
C:\x86_64\release\_obsolete\python3-psycopg2\python3-psycopg2-2.8.4-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\exiv2\exiv2-0.26-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\expat\expat-2.1.0-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\gdal\gdal-3.1.4-3.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\gdal\python3-gdal\python3-gdal-3.1.4-3.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\geos\geos-3.8.1-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\gpsbabel\gpsbabel-1.4.4-2.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\gsl\gsl-libs\gsl-libs-1.15-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\hdf5\hdf5-1.10.5-5.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\iconv\iconv-1.14-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\libpq\libpq-11.5-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\libspatialindex\libspatialindex-1.9.0-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\libzip\libzip-libs\libzip-libs-1.2.0-2.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\msvcrt\msvcrt-1.0.3-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\msvcrt\msvcrt2015\msvcrt2015-2.0-2.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\opencl\opencl-2.0.10-5.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\openssl\openssl-1.1.1d-2.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\proj\proj-6.3.2-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\protobuf\protobuf-3.11.4-2.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\pyqt5\pyqt5-5.11.3-2.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-certifi\python3-certifi-2020.4.5.2-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-chardet\python3-chardet-3.0.4-2.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-core\python3-core-3.7.0-4.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-coverage\python3-coverage-4.5.1-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-future\python3-future-0.16.0-2.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-httplib2\python3-httplib2-0.11.3-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-idna\python3-idna-2.9-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-jinja2\python3-jinja2-2.11.1-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-markupsafe\python3-markupsafe-1.1.1-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-mock\python3-mock-2.0.0-2.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-nose2\python3-nose2-0.8.0-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-numpy\python3-numpy-1.19.1-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-owslib\python3-owslib-0.20.0-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-pbr\python3-pbr-4.3.0-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-plotly\python3-plotly-4.8.2-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-psycopg2-binary\python3-psycopg2-binary-2.8.4-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-pygments\python3-pygments-2.5.2-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-pyproj\python3-pyproj-2.6.1.post1-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-python-dateutil\python3-python-dateutil-2.8.1-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-pytz\python3-pytz-2020.1-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-pyyaml\python3-pyyaml-5.3.1-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-qscintilla\python3-qscintilla-2.10.8-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-requests\python3-requests-2.23.0-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-retrying\python3-retrying-1.3.3-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-six\python3-six-1.15.0-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-urllib3\python3-urllib3-1.25.9-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\python3\sip-qt5\sip-qt5-4.19.14-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\qgis\qgis-common\qgis-common-3.18.3-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qca-qt5\qca-qt5-libs\qca-qt5-libs-2.1.3-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qscintilla-qt5\qscintilla-qt5-2.10.8-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qt5-libs\qt5-libs-5.11.2-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qt5-qml\qt5-qml-5.11.2-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qt5-tools\qt5-tools-5.11.2-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qtkeychain-qt5\qtkeychain-qt5-libs\qtkeychain-qt5-libs-0.9-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qtwebengine-qt5\qtwebengine-qt5-libs\qtwebengine-qt5-libs-5.10.1-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qtwebkit-qt5\qtwebkit-qt5-libs\qtwebkit-qt5-libs-5.212-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qwt\qwt-libs-qt5\qwt-libs-qt5-6.1.3-5.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\shell\shell-1.0.2-4.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\spatialite\spatialite-4.3.0a-6.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\sqlite3\sqlite3-3.29.0-1.tar.bz2
C:\x86_64\release\zlib\zlib-1.2.8-1.tar.bz2
```

Comment: I'd like to install 64bits programs because my PC is 64bits... I'm afraid the setup ends up thinking the programs are 32bits and complains about loading DLLs that are not missing, but maybe not the expected version

Comment: This is a good question. Seems to me like you have a Win7 32-bits machine and trying to install OsGeo4W network installer. You can install the last QGIS 3.18 standalone version, too. But, what happen if you try install the last 32-bit version of network installer: https://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/v1/x86/osgeo4w-setup-x86.exe?

Comment: I am 100% sure my system is 64bits

Comment: Ok. And why are you running osgeo4w-setup.exe? Can you try with osgeo4w-setup-x86_64-v1.exe from https://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/v1/?

Comment: Actually I tried with both versions and it makes no difference

Comment: Will be hard to find solution here. We need to try download the same packages and install from network installer but in local mode, the same packages as you. If you can't install in Network mode, and if you don't want the last QGIS win7 compatible stand-alone version, seems better to me if you contact osgeo4w-dev mail list: https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/osgeo4w-dev

Comment: I basically downloaded all the files listed as required by "qgis" in setup.ini. I can't install from network as it will force Python 3.9 and even the stand-alone 3.18.3 comes with Python 3.9 so I am kind of stuck with my Win7 PC here... :-( Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try

Comment: V1 Network installed wasn't forced to Python 3.7? Wasn't https://download.qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.18.3-1-Setup-x86_64.exe the last QGIS 64-bits stand-alone installer, Python 3.7 compatible?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca my apologies, I realized I was sloppy and I didn't actually download all required files (there are 93 in total and I got only 61), I managed to download all required files and the setup worked out perfectly. Again, my apologies for wasting your time

Comment: Hi! Don't worry, it's good to know that you was able to perform the local installation.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I did not actually download all the required files.
I was sloppy and I didn't go all the way to the bottom of each branch of the dependencies tree.

This is the actual list, there are 93 files and not 61 like I initially got:

```
C:\x86_64\release\_obsolete\msvc2015\msvc2015-1.0.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\_obsolete\python3-psycopg2\python3-psycopg2-2.8.4-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\boost\boost-libs\boost-libs-1.56.0-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\curl\curl-7.67.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\curl\curl-ca-bundle\curl-ca-bundle-20191119-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\exiv2\exiv2-0.26-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\expat\expat-2.1.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\freexl\freexl-1.0.2-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\gdal\gdal-3.1.4-3.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\gdal\python3-gdal\python3-gdal-3.1.4-3.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\geos\geos-3.8.1-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\gpsbabel\gpsbabel-1.4.4-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\gsl\gsl-libs\gsl-libs-1.15-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\hdf4\hdf4-4.2.14-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\hdf5\hdf5-1.10.5-5.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\iconv-vc14\iconv-vc14-1.15-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\iconv\iconv-1.14-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\libjpeg\libjpeg\libjpeg-6b-4.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\libjpeg\libjpeg12\libjpeg12-6b-4.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\libkml\libkml-1.3.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\liblwgeom\liblwgeom-3.0.0-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\libmysql\libmysql-6.1.9-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\libpng-vc14\libpng-vc14-1.6.29-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\libpng\libpng-1.6.3-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\libpq\libpq-11.5-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\libspatialindex\libspatialindex-1.9.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\libtiff\libtiff-4.0.8-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\libxml2\libxml2-2.9.1-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\libzip\libzip-libs\libzip-libs-1.2.0-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\msvcrt\msvcrt-1.0.3-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\msvcrt\msvcrt2008\msvcrt2008-1.0.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\msvcrt\msvcrt2010\msvcrt2010-1.0.0-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\msvcrt\msvcrt2012\msvcrt2012-1.0.0-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\msvcrt\msvcrt2015\msvcrt2015-2.0-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\netcdf\netcdf-4.7.3-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\ogdi\ogdi-4.1.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\opencl\opencl-2.0.10-5.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\openjpeg\openjpeg-2.3.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\openssl\openssl-1.1.1d-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\openssl\openssl10\openssl10-1.0.2j-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\proj\proj-6.3.2-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\proj\proj-datumgrid\proj-datumgrid-1.8-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\proj\proj-hpgn\proj-hpgn-1.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\protobuf\protobuf-3.11.4-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\pyqt5\pyqt5-5.11.3-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-certifi\python3-certifi-2020.4.5.2-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-chardet\python3-chardet-3.0.4-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-core\python3-core-3.7.0-4.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-coverage\python3-coverage-4.5.1-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-future\python3-future-0.16.0-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-httplib2\python3-httplib2-0.11.3-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-idna\python3-idna-2.9-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-jinja2\python3-jinja2-2.11.1-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-markupsafe\python3-markupsafe-1.1.1-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-mock\python3-mock-2.0.0-2.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-nose2\python3-nose2-0.8.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-numpy\python3-numpy-1.19.1-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-owslib\python3-owslib-0.20.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-pbr\python3-pbr-4.3.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-plotly\python3-plotly-4.8.2-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-psycopg2-binary\python3-psycopg2-binary-2.8.4-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-pygments\python3-pygments-2.5.2-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-pyproj\python3-pyproj-2.6.1.post1-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-python-dateutil\python3-python-dateutil-2.8.1-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-pytz\python3-pytz-2020.1-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-pyyaml\python3-pyyaml-5.3.1-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-qscintilla\python3-qscintilla-2.10.8-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-requests\python3-requests-2.23.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-retrying\python3-retrying-1.3.3-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-six\python3-six-1.15.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\python3-urllib3\python3-urllib3-1.25.9-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\python3\sip-qt5\sip-qt5-4.19.14-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\qgis\qgis-common\qgis-common-3.18.3-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\qgis\qgis\qgis-3.18.3-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qca-qt5\qca-qt5-libs\qca-qt5-libs-2.1.3-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qscintilla-qt5\qscintilla-qt5-2.10.8-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qt5-libs\qt5-libs-5.11.2-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qt5-qml\qt5-qml-5.11.2-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qt5-tools\qt5-tools-5.11.2-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qtkeychain-qt5\qtkeychain-qt5-libs\qtkeychain-qt5-libs-0.9-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qtwebengine-qt5\qtwebengine-qt5-libs\qtwebengine-qt5-libs-5.10.1-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qtwebkit-qt5\icu\icu-libs\icu-libs-56.1-5.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qtwebkit-qt5\qtwebkit-qt5-libs\qtwebkit-qt5-libs-5.212-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\qt5\qwt\qwt-libs-qt5\qwt-libs-qt5-6.1.3-5.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\setup\setup-1.0.7-16.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\shell\shell-1.0.2-4.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\spatialite\spatialite-4.3.0a-6.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\sqlite3\sqlite3-3.29.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\szip\szip-2.1.1-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\xerces-c\xerces-c-3.2.0-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\xz\xz-5.2.3-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\zlib\zlib-1.2.8-1.tar.bz2 - OK
C:\x86_64\release\zstd\zstd-1.4.4-1.tar.bz2 - OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing that manually to start with?

```
curl -O http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/v1/osgeo4w-setup-x86_64-v1.exe
osgeo4w-setup-x86_64-v1 -s http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/v1 -O -k -q -P qgis
```

Comment: I tried to install from internet but I kept having an error saying setup.ini couldn't be downloaded so I was stuck.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to install QGIS 3.18.3 (with Python 3.7) on Windows 7, either 32 or 64 bit, is to use the **.exe** OSGeo4W Standalone Installers available at https://download.qgis.org/downloads/?C=M;O=D

[QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.18.3-1-Setup-x86.exe](https://download.qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.18.3-1-Setup-x86.exe) for 32 bit systems

[QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.18.3-1-Setup-x86_64.exe](https://download.qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.18.3-1-Setup-x86_64.exe) for 64 bit systems